# c# Is there any difference between these declarations 1- class objClass; and 2- class objClass = null

Tags: c#, class, oop, declaration

Is there any difference between these declarations?

```
 Animal animal;  
 Animal animal1 = null;
```

Comment: Yes. First one you are expecting the compiler to set the object to its default value and in the second object you are explicitly setting it's value to null which is always a safer approach over the first one.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx.  In summary, the first form will generate a compiler error if you attempt to access the variable before assigning it, the second will generate a runtime error.

Comment: Are those local variable declarations or field declarations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't any *significant* difference. At the end, on the runtime, you will have a variable called `animal` of type `Animal`, whose value would be `null` at the point of definition and later on you would set logically it's value to a non `null` value, in order to use it.

However, some would opt the first rather than the second declaration and vice versa. Furthermore, some would argue that the assignment of `null` in the second case is redundant. For instance, if you use ReSharper, I think that you would noticed a message about the redundancy of setting there the `null`.

Last, but not least I suppose that you define a variable of type `Animal` and later on you try to set it's value (I refer to the first case). If that's the case, you are in a good state. Otherwise, If you had the following snippet:

```
Animal animal;
if(animal==null)
{

}
```

You could get a warning before the compilation and a compilation error with the following description:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'animal'

If you had declared only the variable and you had never used it, you would have gotten a warning with the following description:

> The variable 'animal' is declared but never used

All the above refer to the case of a local variable, if we were in the case of a class variable then the things are a bit differently. If you create a console application and you have the following snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static Animal animal;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(animal==null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You will **not** get any compilation error. You will get only a warning with the following description:

```
Field 'Program.animal' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

Comment: As noted above by Claies, the fact that you explicitly assign a null value in the second form makes the compiler think you intended for this, thus it won't see it as an error if you try to use it before assigning a value.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey I will add also this in my post thanks

Comment: well explained.

Comment: @Spark Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference according to **C# specifications** based on the `context`. In a context of a `method`, the compiler can prove that the first `animal` is not assigned, and so can generate a compiler error on the next line where it is used. C# compiler will not allow you to use a method variable if the compiler can prove that is was not assigned.

However, if `animal` is a **Class Field** it will be **automatically initialized** to the default value and the compiler will not generate an error.

**Below is the C# Specification:**

> 5.3 Definite assignment
>
> At a given location in the executable code of a function member, a
>   variable is said to be definitely assigned if the compiler can prove,
>   by a particular static flow analysis (§5.3.3), that the variable has
>   been automatically initialized or has been the target of at least one
>   assignment.

So for the first, the compiler generates a `"Use of an unassigned local variable"`. While for the second, you are explicitly assigning the variable to `null`, so the compiler should be OK with that.